# how to select records that are "similar" in value

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Let's say I have table1 with a column like this:

```
         minutes     | numeric(5,1)             |
```

and table2 with the same column:

```
         minutes     | numeric(5,1)             |
```

How would I select records from table1 that are within a few minutes difference of values in table2?
Let's say table1 has a value of 5 minutes... I want to look in table2 for records that are either 1 minute more or 1 minute less.

My data in table 1 looks like this:

### minutes

```
 9.9
 0.5
 0.2
 0.4
 1.1
```

so for the first record, I would be looking to match records in table2 that are between 8.9 and 10.9

I'm trying to find the correct key words to google but I haven't been successful.

Answer (score 2):

Take the absolute value of the difference and check to see if it is less than or equal to the desired number.

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on abs(t1.minutes-t2.minutes) <= 1
```

Comment: Functions like that prevent sql engine from using indices. More verbose `t2.minutes between t1.minutes -1 and t1.minutes+1` is the sql way of doing such business.